# Biztalk Server 2013 "Join an existing Biztalk group" greyed out

Tags: configuration, server, biztalk

Biztalk novice here.

I have a first Biztalk server correctly configured.
Via the admin console, I've added the second one.
Now, on the second one, I'm configuring Biztalk, and pointing it where I have to the correct SQL server, with the correct accounts.

However, in the "Groups" tab, "Join an existing Biztalk group" is greyed out, and I can't figure out why.

Did you encountered the case before ? What can I do ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was using the Branch edition. I need the Enterprise edition to do so.